# partial rendering with Inertia (Laravel)

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-9

I want to ask if it is possible to render just a component.

For example, I have PageComponent List.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in list">
            <Item :item="item"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Component Item.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{item.update}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <button @click="toggleUpdate">{{item.update ? 'no update' : 'update'}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'
const props = defineProps({
    item: Object
})

function toggleUpdate() {
    Inertia.post(route('api.item.updateValue', props.item.id), {
        'field': 'update',
        'value': !props.item.update ? 1 : 0,
    },
        {
            preserveState: true,
            preserveScroll: true,
            onSuccess: (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                props.item.update = response.props.item.update.value
            }
        })
}
</script>
```

having route in api.php

```
    Route::post('/item/update/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ItemController::class, 'updateValue'])->name('api.item.updateValue');
```

and controller ItemController.php

```
public function updateValue(Request $request){
    $item = $this->itemRepository->getById($request->id);
    $item->{$request->field} = $request->value;
    $item->save();
    
    return Inertia::render('Item', [
        'item' => $item
    ]);
}
```

Is this possible with Inertia or do I have to use classic REST API SPA?

Or what should I change to not send the whole List and render only the changed part of the application.

Comment: first of all in your item.vue const props = defineProps({
    expansion: Object, item: Object,
})

Comment: Thank you. Right is only item prop... I took my code and edited it to became common.